# How to overlay keyboard in React Native?

Tags: react-native

Are there any possible ways to overlay the top layer on the keyboard? I tried zIndex, modal, nothing works. In order to better understand what we are talking about, see the pictures.

[image]

Comment: Are you willing to customize the default system keyboard?

Comment: I don't want to customize the default system keyboard, because it can lead to problems in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also ran up against this problem while building a chat app. My solution may not be the best, but it was good enough for us. We wanted to render an image picker in the same frame as the keyboard, basically "replacing" it when picking an image, and then showing the keyboard again when the image had been picked.

First we needed to know how the height of the keyboard on the device. For that, we waited for the first `keyboardDidShow` event and stored the height of the keyboard after that. Now when we need to render our image picker, we know what height to give it.

To render the image picker, we do a `Keyboard.dismiss` while also setting the state of the image picker to `rendered`. This causes a bad-looking "blip" where the content above the keyboard shifts down when the keyboard is dismissed and then shifts back up again once the image picker is rendered. We fixed this by setting the height of the container "above" the keyboard to be constant. Then when the keyboard is dismissed, the content above the keyboard does not shift down and things look smooth. You can even animate your "modal" rendering, w/e.

Going from the image picker back to the keyboard is the same basic concept. Hide the picker and show the keyboard. For that, we "focus" the text input, which shows the keyboard automatically.

It's worth noting that iOS and Android handle keyboard events differently. Android does not support `willShow` and `willHide` events, and also bumps your main content container upward when the keyboard shows. iOS shows the keyboard on top (z-index) of your content so you have to shift it upward yourself.

If this is the kind of answer you're looking for I could post some sample code. It's really not quite as complicated as it all sounds you just have to play with it until it works.

Comment: It would be cool if you published your code, but actually this question refers to another question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57447880/how-to-get-keyboard-height-before-it-opens-in-react-native. If you can answer this question will be very cool!